# How to tell which partition is for windows

Tags: arch-linux, partition, windows

So I am currently on my arch linux machine and I have forgotten which partition is for Windows 7. Is there any way for me to tell which is which?

When I do:

```
$ cat /proc/partitions
```

I get:

```
 major minor  #blocks  name

 8        0  488386584 sda
 8        1   17408000 sda1
 8        2  403598873 sda2
 8        3          1 sda3
 8        5    4122624 sda5
 8        6   63254528 sda6
11        0    1048575 sr0
```

But I am not totally sure how to use that to determine which is my Windows partition.

Comment: Do `sudo blkid`, and look for NTFS filesystems.

Comment: Choose one tool: `fdisk -l`, `parted -l`, `lsblk -f` and look for *large* `ntfs` fs.

Comment: No need for root/sudo: `lsblk -lo name,fstype,partflags` and look for NTFS; if your drive is mbr, the one with `0x80` is your win7 root partition.

Comment: great, got it figured out and mounted

Comment: @don_crissti oddly enough, I can't get a single filesystem type on Ubuntu without `sudo` for `lsblk`.

Comment: lsblk -lo name,fstype | grep ntfs. No need for sudo here too (Arch Linux).

Comment: @don_crissti Indeed they do, since [their manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/blkid.8.html) says no such thing. :D

Comment: @muru - :D great... that makes my comment completely irrelevant. They prolly have their reasons for doing all that (beyond me, anyway).

Answer (score 2):

You can't tell what each partition is for from `/proc/partitions`, that only tells you the partition numbers and their sizes. Given the numbering, with a one-sector `sda3` and no partition numbered 4, this is an [MBR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record)-type partition table where `sda3` is an [extended partition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_boot_record); since Windows needs to boot from a primary partition, the Windows partition has to be either `sda1` (17GB) or `sda2` (400GB).

You can list the partition types — that should tell you which one is Windows. It's possible to install Linux on a partition marked with a DOS/Windows type, because Linux for the most part doesn't care about partition types, but that's not recommended because it's confusion-prone, and typical installers won't do that.

```
fdisk -l /dev/sda
```

Another way would be to list the filesystem types on each partition. The one that's NTFS is Windows.

```
file -s /dev/sda[0-9]*
```

If the partition is mounted (or, by a process of elimination, if it's the one that's not mounted), you can run `df -T` or `cat /proc/mounts` to list the mounted partitions with the filesystem types and their mount points.